# thickbox overlay incorrect in ie6/7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, thickbox

hello
i am using thickbox with jquery. however in ie6/7 with the standard css that comes with thickbox it works ok with ie8 and ff but not ie7. i have tried a hack but that dosent work. (posted below). what happens is that if i use the hack it dosne't affect the transparent overlay at all. if i do not use the hack it only shows 50% of the page transparent. can someone show me where to troubleshoot this? many thanks

```
#TB_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#TB_overlay { position: absolute; z-index:100; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: #000000; filter:alpha(opacity=85); -moz-opacity: 0.7; opacity: 0.75; min-height:100%; height: auto; _height:100%; /* pour IE 6 */ height : 1px; } /* pour les autres navigateurs */ 

* > #TB_overlay { height: auto; } /* pour IE 7 */ 

*+html #TB_overlay { min-height : 1px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (modified from fancybox's css):

```
#TB_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 100;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

* html #TB_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    height: expression(document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight ? document.body.scrollHeight : document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem in Firefox but it works if:

```
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
```

cheers